# simple question on gamma functions monotonicity

Tags: gamma-function

Consider $x> 1$ and $i=1,2,3...$. I do not know much about gamma functions.

Is $\Gamma(x) < \Gamma(x+i), \forall i$? I know there is some property that gamma function is always increasing in $(\alpha, \infty)$ when $\alpha >2$.

Comment: Weird way to express that it is increasing in $(2,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the plot. https://www.google.com/search?biw=1680&bih=902&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=5QxnXL6dAsP5sAfMoYa4DQ&q=gamma+function+plot&oq=gamma+function+plot&gs_l=img.3..0i19.7839.8517..8973...0.0..0.69.299.5......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i8i30i19.2i3y2oLz0xM

Comment: You want to say the answer is "YES"?

Comment: Didn't you answer yourself ?